# Nilpotency of a Lie algebra versus nilpotency of its derived subalgebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

For a Lie algebra $L$, it is clear that if $L' = [L,L]$ is solvable, then $L$ is solvable. For nilpotent this is no longer true. What is an example of an $L$ for which $[L,L]$ is nilpotent but $L$ is not?

Comment: Look at easy examples for such questions, e.g. take $L$ as the unique non-abelian $2$-dimensional Lie algebra with basis $(x,y)$ and $[x,y]=x$. Of course $[L,L]$ is nilpotent, it is even abelian. And $L$ is not nilpotent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any solvable algebra $L$  which is not nilpotent. $[L,L]$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Good point! Thanks!